# Java Regex : How to ignore a set of words

Tags: java, regex, regex-negation

I have this `(.*)([USB][\s])*` as a part of a regex. When i'm trying to match it with `ABHISHEK USB` it matches but full value matches with the first part. Is there any way by which i can ignore `USB` part from `(.*)` and have it matched to `([USB][\s])`.

Comment: Please share some examples of what should match and what should not

Comment: This seems to be a very specific case. What about [`(.*?)(\s*USB)*$`](https://regex101.com/r/sW0zU6/1)? Note that here, `USB` should be at the end of the string. Please add more specifications to the question if it does not meet your need. Also note that `[USB]` matches 1 character, either `U` or `S` or `B`. And please let know if you need to match `ABHISHEK` with the regex, too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The star (`*`) says repeat **zero** or more times. This is done greedily. Therefore, the problem is that `.*` will try to match everything, and since the second star can match **zero** characters, no backtracking is performed. Two solutions:

1. If you are sure, the `(\sUSB)*` part will be present, use `+` instead of `*` to repeat **one** or more times:

   ```
   (.*)(\sUSB)+
   ```
2. If that is not the case, use non-greedy repetition for the first star - `.*?`:

   ```
   (.*?)(\sUSB)*
   ```

Answer (score 0):

Try this regex:

```
(.*)(?=USB[\s]*)
```

https://regex101.com/r/bG8vB4/1

Answer (score 0):

I guess you are looking for this :

```
(.*?)\s*USB\s*
```

Note that, I changed your `[USB]` into `USB`

since `[USB]` matches `U or S or B` not string `USB`

Also I change the `.*` into non-greedy one, with the `?`.

Answer (score 0):

You have a greedy quantifier in your regex. 
Check Java Tutorial [Differences Among Greedy, Reluctant, and Possessive Quantifiers](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/regex/quant.html)

```
public class Test {
      @org.junit.Test
      public void testRegx() {

        String s = "(.*?)(USB)(.*)";
        String value = "ABHISHEK USB \\t";
        Matcher m = Pattern.compile(s).matcher(value);
        if(m.matches()) {
          Assert.assertEquals("ABHISHEK ", m.group(1));
          Assert.assertEquals("USB", m.group(2));
          Assert.assertEquals(" \\t", m.group(3));
        } else {
          Assert.assertFalse(true);
        }

      }
}
```